# Importing a data file with names

Tags: import, data

I have the following [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7wixr73wbyfp1e0/Exo_data.txt/file) which contains four columns of data

However when I import it as

```
data = Import["Exo_data.txt", "Table"];
```

I get the following list

```
data = {{11, "Com", "b", 19.4, 0.231, 2.7}, {11, "Oph", "b", 21, 0.0162},
        {11, "UMi", "b", 10.5, 0.08, 1.8}, {14, "And", "b", 5.33, 0, 2.2}, ...}
```

The first column of the data file contains the names, e.g., 11 Com b, however when I Import it the name is split into multiple columns. I want to obtain the following list

```
data = {{"11 Com b", 19.4, 0.231, 2.7}, {"11 Oph b", 21, 0.0162},
        {"11 UMi b", 10.5, 0.08, 1.8}, {"14 And b", 5.33, 0, 2.2}, ...}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does ReadList["Exo_data.txt"] work?

Comment: or data = Import["Exo_data.txt", "List"]

Comment: @user49047 None of them work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `"FieldSeparators"` option for the `"Table"` import format:

```
Import[
 "exo_data.txt",
 "Table",
 "FieldSeparators" -> {"\t"},
 "RepeatedSeparators" -> False,
 HeaderLines -> 1
 ]

(* {
     {"11 Com b", 19.4, 0.231, 2.7},
     {"11 Oph b", 21, "", 0.0162},
     …
   } *)
```

Note the use of `"RepeatedSeparators"->False` to preserve the empty entries in some of the rows.

If you want to preserve the headers, you could do the following:

```
Dataset@
 Query[Transpose]@
  (AssociationThread[First@# -> Transpose@Rest@#] &)@
   Import[
     "exo_data.txt",
     "Table",
     "FieldSeparators" -> {"\t"},
     "RepeatedSeparators" -> False
     ][[;; -5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that using `SemanticImport` with tab as a delimiter does what you want:

```
SemanticImport["~/Downloads/Exo_data.txt", Delimiters -> "\t"]
```

[image]